# In slick slider I want to perform filter action on button selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I want to build a filtering action on slick carousel.
I have multiple buttons, on button click it should filter(as there will be large no.of carousel cards after selection also slick slider should work).
I tried doing slick('refresh') on button click, however it's coming as undefined.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.